# Smart Form changes not reflecting in site. #Ektron

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

I have edited my existing smart form in smart form configurations in settings menu.
Then I have published and updated the smart form in contents folder properties.
Now I went to particular content which is using that particular smart form in CMS 400 editor and  I can see the changes.
But when I go through the page in browser it still shows the old smart form.Unable to reflect changes in browser. please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know what version you're running.  That being said, there are a few things that could be going on here...

#### Caching

FrameworkAPI caching might be turned on, in which case you'd have to wait for the cache expiration or recycle the app pool in order to see updated content.  Caching is enabled in web.config by changing the `defaultContainer` property in this section to Cache.

```xml
<ektron.framework.services>
  <unity configSource="ektron.cms.framework.unity.config"/>
  <framework defaultContainer="Default" childContainer="BusinessObjects"/>
</ektron.framework.services>
```

#### Republish the content

Changes to a smart form definition won't immediately trickle down to all content blocks using that particular smart form.  If you add a field (for instance), that field won't exist on any content blocks unless you open up that content block in edit mode and republish it.  It will automatically be added to the content block when you click Edit, but that change won't be saved until you click publish.

Comment: It was caching problem.. Now it is solved. Thanks for the help Brian.